# typo3 blank page at backend-login

Tags: php, typo3, backend

I installed a typo3-site on my local machine that I downloaded from an FTP-Server (just to make local tests instead of working with the live-page).
Downloaded and installed the database as well, changed the localcon.php accordingly.

Everything works fine on the frontend, but when I try to login to the backend, all I get is a blank page after entering username/password.

I tracked it down to the init.php in the folder typo3 - there, the script dies after this line: `$BE_USER->start();         // Object is initialized`

I deleted the cached files, emptied the be_session-table... checked the password... everything seems to be ok...

Any ideas?

Comment: What TYPO3 version do you have?

Comment: 4.5.x - I know, old version...

Comment: Make sure to turn on error reporting to see the real error.